# How to prevent circular binding dependency

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, data-binding, javafx-8

I am trying to create a textfield that has an image part within itself, similar to [this](http://webuikits.com/sign-in-widget/).

```
imageView.fitHeightProperty().bind(Bindings.createDoubleBinding(
    () -> textField.getHeight() -
          textField.getPadding().getTop() -
          textField.getPadding().getBottom(),
    textField.heightProperty(), textField.paddingProperty()));

imageView.fitWidthProperty().bind(imageView.fitHeightProperty());

textField.paddingProperty().bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(
    () -> new Insets(textField.getPadding().getTop(),
                     textField.getPadding().getRight(),
                     textField.getPadding().getBottom(),
                     textField.getPadding().getRight() * 2 + imageView.getFitWidth()),
    imageView.fitWidthProperty(), textField.paddingProperty()));
```

My current approach is to use a `StackPane` to hold the `TextField`, then also add an `ImageView` as the `StackPane`'s child. The `ImageView` needs to know how resize itself, so I have bound its `fitHeight` to the `TextField`'s height, with consideration of the `TextField`'s padding.

The `ImageView`'s `fitWidth` is then bound to its own `fitHeight`.

Lastly, I need to make my `TextField`'s text offset to the right (because the image is blocking it), so I once again did another binding that is dependent on the `ImageView`'s `fitWidth`.

This ends up with circular dependency, which causes the stack to overflow. Is there any other way to do it without hard coding the `TextField`'s left padding?

Comment: Why do you need to resize the image ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little exemple, i've used (`StackPane/TextField/ImageView`) but instead of the Image i advise you to draw your own shape with `SVG` to have the full control on it (MouseHover/Focused...), i've also used a CSS to achieve this :

Java :

```
    private StackPane sp = new StackPane();
    private TextField tf = new TextField();
    private ImageView iv;

    //Init StackPane
    sp.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm()); 
    sp.getStyleClass().add("identifiant");
    sp.setPrefSize(200, 40);
    sp.setLayoutX(100);
    sp.setLayoutY(100);

    //Init ImageView
    iv = new ImageView(getClass().getResource("Img.png").toString());
    StackPane.setAlignment(iv, Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
    StackPane.setMargin(iv, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 10));

    //Init TextField
    StackPane.setAlignment(tf, Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
    StackPane.setMargin(tf, new Insets(2, 5, 0, 30));

    //Add all content
    sp.getChildren().addAll(iv,tf);
```

Css :

```
.identifiant{

-fx-background-color:#45444a;
-fx-effect:innershadow(three-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0) , 6, 0.0 , 0 , 0); 
-fx-background-radius:8px;
 }

.text-field{

-fx-background-insets:0;
-fx-background-color:#45444a;
-fx-text-fill:white;
}
```

Hope this will help you !